# MySQL returning null value after cell was updated

Tags: python, mysql, sql, json

I am having a little MySQL issue.  I wrote a python script that records click throughs and handles redirects.  I have a table where for a given ip address, there are various columns including a column that contains a list of id's.  If a user has never click on an image (the row will still exist), then the cell contains a empty list.

Note that the lists are serialized as strings using json before being updated in the table.  I know that this is not always a good practice but for our application it seems to work.

So before a user has clicked on an image, the sql table can be queried:

```
    sql = """select clicked_id from `""" + DBTABLE2 + """`
            where ip='%s'"""%(ip_address,)     
    cur.execute(sql)
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row:
        ci = row['clicked_id']
        print ci, type(ci)

        clicked_id=json.loads(ci)
        print clicked_id, type(clicked_id)
```

The print statements return:

```
    []  <type 'str'>
    []  <type 'list'>
```

However, after you run the following python script (which run successfully) the output is completely different.  Here is the python code:

```
#connecting to the mysql table
con = mysql.connect(host=DBHOST, user=DBUSERNAME, passwd=DBPASSWORD,
                db=DBDATABASE, cursorclass=DictCursor)
cur = con.cursor()

#save the click through
sql = """select clicked_id from `""" + DBTABLE2 + """`
                where ip='%s'"""%(ip_address,)     
cur.execute(sql)
row = cur.fetchone()
if row:
    clicked_id = row['clicked_id']

    #decoding the data
    clicked_id = json.loads(clicked_id)

else:
    clicked_id=[]

#Updating the list
clicked_id = clicked_id.append(product_id)

#Encoding the data
clicked_id = json.dumps(clicked_id)

#Updating the mysql database
cur.execute("""update `"""+DBTABLE2+"""` set clicked_id='%s' where ip='%s'"""%(clicked_id,ip_address,))

#Getting the dst url
sql = """select url from `""" + DBTABLE + """`
                where id='%s'"""%(product_id,)
cur.execute(sql)
row = cur.fetchone()

if row:
    url = row['url']
```

Checking the table again, the print statements return:

```
 null  <type 'str'>
 None  <type 'NoneType'>
```

I have no idea why it is doing this...  I GREATLY appreciate any help!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I am kind of new so I didn't realize that I could/should accept answers.

Comment: Ha, no worries - I think a lot of people have that confusion. You're looking good now (and welcome to the community :) ).

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the python script where it says:

```
    #Updating the list
    clicked_id = clicked_id.append(product_id)
```

This is incorrect and gives clicked_id a NoneType, which when loaded into MySQL is interpreted as a null value.

Simply update the code to:

```
    clicked_id.append(product_id)
```